# Toilet flange is too long and can't lower pipe in floor

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flange

I have new plumbing installed for a new toilet. However, the 4" pipe is too close to the floor so the toilet flange (not yet installed) is too long and sticks above the finished floor about an inch. The pipe can't be lowered due to space issues. Is there anyway I can install this flange (or a different one?) that would make the flange lower and flush with the floor or, although not ideal, sitting on top of it? Also should mention that the pipe does not go straight down like the picture makes it seem. It is an elbow right at the floor.

Here is a crude illustration of the floor and the issue with the flange.

[image]

Comment: If you can provide photos it could help us propose what parts to use and where/how to trim them to fit. If the flange is going into the socket of a fitting, does the flange bottom out in that socket? It's usually OK for the flange to sit above the finished floor surface, but an inch is probably excessive. You can measure the bottom of the toilet to determine how tall the stack of flange and wax ring can/should be.

Comment: @GregHill I will try to get pictures. The flange fits INSIDE the pipe. The flange pushes inside until it stops which leaves about an inch above the floor. I should also mention that the pipe's end had about 1/2 to 3/4" trimmed off of it to bring it below the floor level.

Comment: In your illustration on the right, what is the length of the "too long" portion? Is there another flange available that has a shorter portion that fits inside your drain?

Comment: I think there's enough detail here and I'd like to post an answer. Voting to reopen.